# Javascript : How to get the key value json format in an array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have successfully sent array with object string from front to backend in this application.However, I want to return a particular type of JSON format from my mongoDb database.What I got is not actually what I want.

```
Current JSON Format :
```

```
"urlPath": [
        "{\"urlString\":\"http://www.goals.com\"}",
        "{\"urlString\":\"http://www.trandent.com\"}"   
    ],
```

```
Desired JSON format :
```

```
"urlPath": [
        {"urlString":"http://www.goals.com"},
        {"urlString":"http://www.trandent.com"}   
    ],
```

Controller :

```
exports.addUrl = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const urls = Object.assign({},req.body)
  const email=req.params.email;
  console.log(email)
  const{users}=urls


  if (urls) {
console.log('url exists')
    Resume.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        email,
      },
      { $push: { urlPath: { $each: users } } },    
      {
        new: true,
        fields: {
          urlPath : 1,
        },
      }
    ).exec((err, results) => {    
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(results);
      console.log('Submitted successfully!')     
    });
  }
});
```

And here is the client side code :

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const email=user.email
    const frmData = new FormData();

    this.state.users.forEach((user) =>
      frmData.append('users',JSON.stringify(user))
    );
    console.log(frmData);
    
    
    axios.post(`/api/url/${email}`,frmData).then(
      (res) => {
        alert('Submitted successfully!');
      },

      (err) => {
        if (err.response.status === 500) alert(err.response.data);
      }
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

How do i manipulate data at the backend to give me the desired JSON output as stated above?

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate over the array and json parse each element, fortunately javascript has [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which makes this trivial. the following code will do it.

```
let parsedData = {}
parsedData.urlPath = rawData.urlPath.map((rawEntry) => JSON.parse(rawEntry))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but at what point is this code useful, before its saved in DB  ? and I dont really get the LHS of the code "parsedData.urlPath"  urlPath is actually the Array field in the database? could you just help me understand your code a bit. thanks in advance

Comment: its simply taking the  output from your db -`{ "urlPath": [
        "{\"urlString\":\"http://www.goals.com\"}",
        "{\"urlString\":\"http://www.trandent.com\"}"   
    ]}`, and converting it to `{"urlPath": [
        {"urlString":"http://www.goals.com"},
        {"urlString":"http://www.trandent.com"}   
    ]}` - its doing this by creating an empty object `parsedData`, and adding the property 'urlPath', whose value is the new array created by the map function. The map is iterating over the original array adding the result of JSON.parse, to the same position in the new array

Comment: Ok, i think i understand, but one last question, if urlPath is coming from DB, what then is  rawData?  shouldn't it be just urlPath.map()  instead of rawData.urlPath.map( ) ?

Comment: rawData is the object coming from the DB